# Template binary heap with lambda function comparator C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, template, lambda, heap

This heap will be used for A* search pathfinding in my 2D isometric game engine. It uses lambda functions (instead of `std::less` or `std::greater`) to allow me to dictate min-heap or max-heap more dynamically. It also uses lambda functions for `FindByKey`, `ReplaceByKey`, and `RemoveByKey` so that the search key can differ from the compare key (for example: sorting by priority, but searching by name).

Typical use:

```
typedef struct test_s {
    int priority;
    std::string name;
    test_s(): priority(rand() % 100), name("DEFAULT_TEST") {};
} test_t;

auto max = [](test_t & a, test_t & b) { return b.priority > a.priority; };
auto equls = [](test_t & a, std::string key) { return a.name == key; };
eHeap<test_t, decltype(max)> priorityQueue(max);
test_t * result;

priorityQueue.PushHeap(test_t());    
if (result = priorityQueue.FindByKey("DEFAULT_TEST", equls) != nullptr)
    printf("Found %s\n", result->name);
// etc
```

The primary data structure is a c-style array because I wanted the practice, so the heap arrangement only works on contiguous memory blocks. Dynamic memory allocation for the array occurs in block sizes given by the `granularity` as seen in `Resize(const int newHeapSize)` to reduce allocation overhead. The allocated memory is only freed on `ClearAndResize(const int newHeapSize)`, `~eHeap()`, or if the `public` `Free()` is called.

I've unit-tested this with POD types, `std::string`, and `std::unique_ptr<int>` and it executes all functions without issue.

**Question: Are there any memory leak/corruption issues I'm not seeing?**

```
#ifndef EVIL_HEAP_H
#define EVIL_HEAP_H

#include <new.h>        // std::move
#include <utility>      // std::swap

#define DEFAULT_HEAP_SIZE 1024
#define DEFAULT_HEAP_GRANULARITY 1024

//********************************************
//              eHeap
// The template compare function a user creates 
// dictates if this is a MaxHeap or a MinHeap.
// Does not allocate until a new element is added.
// This copies/moves pushed data, so changing 
// the source data will not affect this heap.
// This class only works with contiguous memory.
//*******************************************
template <class type, class lambdaCompare>
class eHeap {
public:

    typedef eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> heap_t;

                            eHeap() = delete;                                                           // disallow instantiation without lambdaCompare object      
                            eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, const int initialHeapSize = DEFAULT_HEAP_SIZE);// relaced default constructor
                            eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, const type * data, const int numElements);   // heapify copy constructor 
                            eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, type * data, const int numElements);         // heapify move constructor 
                            eHeap(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other);                            // copy constructor
                            eHeap(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other);                                 // move constructor
                            ~eHeap();                                                                   // destructor

    heap_t                  operator+(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other);                        // copy merge
    heap_t                  operator+(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other);                             // move merge
    heap_t &                operator+=(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other);                       // copy meld
    heap_t &                operator+=(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other);                            // move meld
    heap_t &                operator=(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> other);                                // copy and swap assignement
    const type * const      operator[](const int index) const;                                          // debug const content access   

    const type * const      PeekRoot() const;
    void                    PushHeap(const type & data);
    void                    PushHeap(type && data);
    void                    PopRoot();
    void                    ReplaceRoot(const type & data);
    void                    ReplaceRoot(type && data);

    // DEBUG: universal/forwarding references
    template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
    const type * const      FindByKey(DataMember && key, lambdaEquals & equals) const;  

    template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
    bool                    RemoveByKey(DataMember && key, lambdaEquals & equals);

    template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
    bool                    ReplaceByKey(DataMember && oldKey, type & newData, lambdaEquals & equals);

    template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
    bool                    ReplaceByKey(DataMember && oldKey, type && newData, lambdaEquals & equals);

    int                     Size() const;
    bool                    IsEmpty() const;

    // memory management
    size_t                  Allocated() const;
    void                    SetGranularity(const int newGranularity);
    void                    Free();
    void                    Resize(const int newHeapSize);
    void                    Clear();
    void                    ClearAndResize(const int newHeapSize);

private:

    void                    Allocate(const int newHeapSize);
    void                    Heapify();
    void                    SiftUp(const int index);
    void                    SiftDown(const int index);

private:

    type *                  heap;           
    lambdaCompare           compare;
    int                     numElements;
    int                     granularity;
    int                     heapSize;
};

//***************
// eHeap::eHeap
// default constructor
//*****************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, const int initialHeapSize) 
    : compare(compare),
      numElements(0),
      granularity(DEFAULT_HEAP_GRANULARITY),
      heapSize(initialHeapSize),
      heap(nullptr) 
{
}

//***************
// eHeap::eHeap
// heapify copy constructor
// only works on contiguous memory
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, const type * data, const int numElements) 
    : compare(compare),
      numElements(numElements),
      granularity(DEFAULT_HEAP_GRANULARITY)
{
    int mod;
    int i;

    mod = numElements % granularity;
    if (numElements > 0 && !mod) {
        heapSize = numElements;
    } else {
        heapSize = numElements + granularity - mod;
    }

    if (data == nullptr) {
        heap = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    heap = new type[heapSize];
    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        heap[i] = data[i];

    Heapify();
}

//***************
// eHeap::eHeap
// heapify move constructor
// only works on contiguous memory
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::eHeap(lambdaCompare & compare, type * data, const int numElements)
    : compare(compare),
    numElements(numElements),
    granularity(DEFAULT_HEAP_GRANULARITY)
{
    int mod;
    int i;

    mod = numElements % granularity;
    if (numElements > 0 && !mod) {
        heapSize = numElements;
    }
    else {
        heapSize = numElements + granularity - mod;
    }

    if (data == nullptr) {
        heap = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    heap = new type[heapSize];
    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        heap[i] = std::move(data[i]);

    Heapify();
}

//***************
// eHeap::eHeap
// copy constructor
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::eHeap(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other) 
    : compare(other.compare),
      numElements(other.numElements),
      granularity(other.granularity),
      heapSize(other.heapSize)
{
    int i;
    heap = new type[heapSize];
    for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
        heap[i] = other.heap[i];
}

//***************
// eHeap::eHeap
// move constructor
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::eHeap(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other) 
    : compare(other.compare),
      numElements(0),
      granularity(DEFAULT_HEAP_GRANULARITY),
      heapSize(DEFAULT_HEAP_SIZE),
      heap(nullptr) 
{
    std::swap(numElements, other.numElements);
    std::swap(granularity, other.granularity);
    std::swap(heapSize, other.heapSize);
    std::swap(heap, other.heap);
}

//***************
// eHeap::~eHeap
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::~eHeap() {
    Free();
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator+
// merge, copies originals
// DEBUG: cannot be const function because the invoked heapify copy constructor is not const
//****************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator+(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other) {
    int sumElements; 
    int i, j;
    type * newData; 

    sumElements = numElements + other.numElements;
    if (!sumElements)
        return eHeap<type, decltype(compare)>(compare);

    newData = new type[sumElements];
    if (heap != nullptr) {
        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            newData[i] = heap[i];
    }
    if (other.heap != nullptr) {
        for (/*i == numElements,*/ j = 0; j < other.numElements; i++, j++)
            newData[i] = other.heap[j];
    }

    return eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>(compare, newData, sumElements);
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator+
// merge, moves from originals
// DEBUG: cannot be const function because the invoked heapify move constructor is not const
//****************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator+(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other) {
    int sumElements;
    int i, j;
    type * newData;

    sumElements = numElements + other.numElements;
    if (!sumElements)
        return eHeap<type, decltype(compare)>(compare);

    newData = new type[sumElements];
    if (heap != nullptr) {
        for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
            newData[i] = std::move(heap[i]);
    }
    if (other.heap != nullptr) {
        for (/*i == numElements,*/ j = 0; j < other.numElements; i++, j++)
            newData[i] = std::move(other.heap[j]);
    }

    return eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>(compare, newData, sumElements);
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator+=
// meld, moves from source
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator+=(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> && other) {
    int i;

    if (other.heap == nullptr)
        return *this;

    if (heap == nullptr) {
        Allocate(other.heapSize);
    } else if (numElements + other.numElements > heapSize) {
        Resize(heapSize + other.numElements);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < other.numElements; i++)
        heap[i + numElements] = std::move(other.heap[i]);

    numElements += other.numElements;
    Heapify();
    return *this;
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator+=
// meld, preserves source
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator+=(const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & other) {
    int i;

    if (other.heap == nullptr)
        return *this;

    if (heap == nullptr) {
        Allocate(other.heapSize);
    } else if (numElements + other.numElements > heapSize) {
        Resize(heapSize + other.numElements);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < other.numElements; i++)
        heap[i + numElements] = other.heap[i];

    numElements += other.numElements;
    Heapify();
    return *this;
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator=
// copy and swap assignement
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> & eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator=(eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> other) {
    std::swap(numElements, other.numElements);
    std::swap(granularity, other.granularity);
    std::swap(heapSize, other.heapSize);
    std::swap(heap, other.heap);
    // DEBUG: lambdaCompare closure object swap is omitted because both eHeaps already contain relevant instances,
    // as well as to avoid invoking deleted default lambda constructor
    return *this;
}

//***************
// eHeap::operator[]
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline const type * const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::operator[](const int index) const {
    return (heap == nullptr || index >= numElements || index < 0) ? nullptr : &heap[index];
}

//***************
// eHeap::PeekRoot
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline const type * const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::PeekRoot() const {
    return heap == nullptr ? nullptr : &heap[0];
}

//***************
// eHeap::PushHeap
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::PushHeap(const type & data) {
    if (heap == nullptr) {
        Allocate(heapSize);
    } else if (numElements + 1 >= heapSize) {
        Resize(heapSize + 1);
    }
    heap[numElements] = data;
    SiftUp(numElements);
    numElements++;
}

//***************
// eHeap::PeekRoot
// emplace and move
// assumes the given type has a move assignment operator
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::PushHeap(type && data) {
    if (heap == nullptr) {
        Allocate(heapSize);
    } else if (numElements + 1 >= heapSize) {
        Resize(heapSize + 1);
    }
    heap[numElements] = std::move(data);
    SiftUp(numElements);
    numElements++;
}

//***************
// eHeap::PopRoot
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::PopRoot() {
    if (heap == nullptr) {
        return;
    } else if (numElements == 1) {
        Clear();
        return;
    }
    numElements--;
    std::swap(heap[0], heap[numElements]);
    SiftDown(0);
}

//***************
// eHeap::ReplaceRoot
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::ReplaceRoot(const type & data) {
    if (heap == nullptr) {
        PushHeap(data);
        return;
    } 
    heap[0] = data;
    SiftDown(0);
}

//***************
// eHeap::ReplaceRoot
// emplace and move
// assumes the given type has a proper move assignment operator
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::ReplaceRoot(type && data) {
    if (heap == nullptr) {
        PushHeap(std::move(data));
        return;
    }
    heap[0] = std::move(data);
    SiftDown(0);
}

//***************
// eHeap::FindByKey
// search keys can differ from compare keys
// returns pointer to the first match regardless of duplicates
// returns nullptr if key not found
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
inline const type * const eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::FindByKey(DataMember && key, lambdaEquals & equals) const {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        if (equals(heap[i], std::forward<DataMember>(key)))
            return &heap[i];
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//***************
// eHeap::RemoveByKey
// search keys can differ from compare keys
// returns false if key not found
//****************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
inline bool eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::RemoveByKey(DataMember && key, lambdaEquals & equals) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        if (equals(heap[i], std::forward<DataMember>(key))) {
            std::swap(heap[i], std::move(heap[numElements - 1]));
            numElements--;
            SiftDown(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//***************
// eHeap::ReplaceByKey
// search keys can differ from compare keys
// returns false if key not found
// DEBUG: instead of explicit IncreaseKey and DecreaseKey
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
inline bool eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::ReplaceByKey(DataMember && oldKey, type & newData, lambdaEquals & equals) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        if (equals(heap[i], std::forward<DataMember>(oldKey))) {
            heap[i] = newData;
            if (i > 0 && compare(heap[(i - 1) / 2], heap[i])) {
                SiftUp(i);
            } else {
                SiftDown(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//***************
// eHeap::ReplaceByKey
// emplace and move
// search keys can differ from compare keys
// returns false if item not found
//****************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
inline bool eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::ReplaceByKey(DataMember && oldKey, type && newData, lambdaEquals & equals) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
        if (equals(heap[i], std::forward<DataMember>(oldKey))) {
            heap[i] = std::move(newData);
            if (i > 0 && compare(heap[(i - 1) / 2], heap[i])) {
                SiftUp(i);
            } else {
                SiftDown(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//***************
// eHeap::Size
// returns number of elements in the heap
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline int eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Size() const {
    return numElements;
}

//***************
// eHeap::IsEmpty
// returns true for numElements == 0
//***************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline bool eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::IsEmpty() const {
    return numElements == 0;
}

//***************
// eHeap::Heapify
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Heapify() {
    int i;

    // DEBUG: start at the element just above the last leaf child and work upwards
    for (i = numElements / 2; i > 0; i--)
        SiftDown(i - 1);
}

//***************
// eHeap::SiftUp
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::SiftUp(const int index) {
    int parent;
    int child;

    if (heap == nullptr)
        return;

    for (child = index; child > 0; child = parent) {
        parent = (child - 1) / 2;
        if (!compare(heap[parent], heap[child]))
            return;

        std::swap(heap[parent], heap[child]);
    }
}

//***************
// eHeap::SiftDown
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::SiftDown(const int index) {
    int parent;
    int child;

    if (heap == nullptr || numElements <= 1)
        return;

    // DEBUG: a right child's existence (child + 1) implies that a left child exists, but not vis versa
    for (parent = index, child = 2 * parent + 1; child < numElements; child = 2 * parent + 1) {
        if (child + 1 < numElements && compare(heap[child], heap[child + 1]))
            child++;
        if (!compare(heap[parent], heap[child]))
            return;

        std::swap(heap[parent], heap[child]);
        parent = child;
    }
}

//***************
// eHeap::Allocate
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Allocate(const int newHeapSize) {
    Free();
    heapSize = newHeapSize;
    heap = new type[heapSize];                  
    memset(heap, 0, heapSize * sizeof(type));
}

//***************
// eHeap::Allocated
// returns the total memory allocated 
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline size_t eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Allocated() const {
    return heap == nullptr * heapSize * sizeof(type);
}

//***************
// eHeap::SetGranularity
// adjust the amount by which the heap will
// expand when it runs out of memory
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::SetGranularity(const int newGranularity) {
    granularity = newGranularity;
}

//***************
// eHeap::Free
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Free() {
    if (heap != nullptr) {
        delete[] heap;
        heap = nullptr;
    }
    numElements = 0;
}

//***************
// eHeap::Resize
// increase heap size
// and expand available memory
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Resize(const int newHeapSize) {
    type * oldHeap;
    int mod;
    int newSize;
    int i;

    if (newHeapSize <= heapSize)
        return;

    mod = newHeapSize % granularity;
    if (!mod)
        newSize = newHeapSize;
    else
        newSize = newHeapSize + granularity - mod;

    if (heap == nullptr) {
        heapSize = newSize;
        return;
    }

    oldHeap = heap;
    heap = new type[newSize];
    for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
        heap[i] = std::move(oldHeap[i]);

    delete[] oldHeap;
    heapSize = newSize;
}

//***************
// eHeap::Clear
// reset numElements retain allocated memory to be overwritten
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::Clear() {
    // DEBUG: memsetting the contents of a 
    // std::unique_ptr or std::string will cause a leak
    // because its destructor cannot deallocate its original pointer
//  if (heap != nullptr) {
//      memset(heap, 0, heapSize * sizeof(type));
        numElements = 0;
//  }
}

//***************
// eHeap::ClearAndResize
// reset all data and free allocated memory
// set the new heap size to be allocated when the next element is added
//**************
template<class type, class lambdaCompare>
inline void eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>::ClearAndResize(const int newHeapSize) {
    Free();
    heapSize = newHeapSize;
}

#endif /* EVIL_HEAP_H */
```

Comment: `It uses lambda functions (instead of std::lesser or std::greater)` Not really true. You templatize the comparator function (which is good). So you can use any functor like object here. Note: A lambda is just syntactic sugar for creating an anonymous class behind the curtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've unit-tested this with POD types, `std::string`, and `std::unique_ptr<int>` and it executes all functions without issue.

Nice to see you again! :)

As with your deque from last time, I think your coding style is very good but the actual *design* is a bit questionable. (Less so than last time, though.) Consider:

```
template<typename DataMember, typename lambdaEquals>
const type * const FindByKey(DataMember&& key, lambdaEquals& equals) const;  

eHeap<std::string, std::less<>> myHeap;
const std::string *it1 = myHeap.FindByKey("hello", std::equal<>);
const std::string *it2 = myHeap.FindByKey("world", std::equal<>);
const std::string *it3 = myHeap.FindByKey("foo", std::equal<>);
```

Notice that the type `DataMember` in the first two calls is `const char (&)[6]`, because the thing we're perfect-forwarding is an lvalue of type `const char[6]`; and in the third call is `const char (&)[4]`.

If I were designing the API, I'd provide simply

```
template<typename lambdaPredicate>
const type * const FindByKey(lambdaPredicate& equals) const;  

eHeap<std::string, std::less<>> myHeap;
const std::string *it1 = myHeap.FindByKey([](auto&& x){ return x == "hello"; });
const std::string *it2 = myHeap.FindByKey([](auto&& x){ return x == "world"; });
const std::string *it3 = myHeap.FindByKey([](auto&& x){ return x == "foo"; });
```

Now the caller doesn't have to worry about things like "is the `DataMember` the first or second argument to `lambdaEquals`?" or "does `DataMember` secretly have to bear some relationship to `type`?" or anything like that. The *only* parameter the caller needs to worry about is the predicate, which is an opaque lambda type that clearly can do whatever it wants.

Notice that the type `lambdaPredicate` is a different type in all three of the calls here. So we have a little bit more template explosion, maybe; but it'll all be inlined anyway.

Also, at this point, we've got something that's very close to the standard algorithm [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). So we *might* like to get rid of the member-function algorithm and just provide a pair of member functions to create iterators into the unordered elements of the heap:

```
const type *unordered_begin() const { return heap; }
const type *unordered_end() const { return heap + heapSize; }

eHeap<std::string, std::less<>> myHeap;
const std::string *it1 = std::find_if(myHeap.unordered_begin(), myHeap.unordered_end(), [](auto&& x){ return x == "hello"; });
```

---

If we're providing `const` iterators, should we also provide non-`const` iterators?

```
type *unordered_begin() { return heap; }
type *unordered_end() { return heap + heapSize; }
```

Probably not. We don't want to give the user the ability to modify or reorder the heap's elements on the fly; that could break the heap invariant.

---

```
typedef eHeap<type, lambdaCompare> heap_t;
```

Did you know that you can use the name of the template itself as a class-name inside the definition of the template? That is, you could just use `eHeap` in all the places you're currently using `heap_t`, and the compiler would know that you're talking about `eHeap<type, lambdaCompare>`.

In any event, `heap_t` probably shouldn't be a *public* member typedef, should it?

---

```
const type * const      operator[](const int index) const;
```

Of the four `const`s on that line, two are redundant — even harmful. Prefer to write

```
const type *operator[](int index) const;
```

It doesn't matter for primitive types like `int` and `type *`, but if the parameter or the return value were class types, the added `const` would have made a difference:

```
X foo();
const X bar();

X x;
x = foo();  // move assignment
x = bar();  // copy assignment, since `const X` can't be moved-from — oops!
```

I prefer always to write the generic-safe version, even for primitive types, so that neither I nor the readers who come after me need to worry about whether this type is primitive or not — it's just obviously safe, and the reader doesn't need to expend mental effort on it.

---

```
int i;
// ...
for (i = 0; i < heapSize; i++)
    heap[i] = other.heap[i];
```

For the same reason, I write `++i` even when `i++` is just as fast *for integers*. (Well, in that case, it's also because the verb comes first in English. "Increment `i`" reads better than "`i`, increment".)

C++ isn't C89; you should never declare an uninitialized variable if you can possibly help it. Write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < heapSize; ++i)
    heap[i] = other.heap[i];
```

---

The line I `// ...`ed above was `heap = new type[heapSize];`. Why on earth are you using manual memory management in this class? Remember the [Rule of Zero](http://blog.florianwolters.de/educational/2015/01/31/The_Rule_of_Zero/#the-rule-of-zero).

Use `std::vector<type> heap;` and get rid of the `heapSize` member variable (because you have `heap.size()` for that now). This not only protects you against memory leaks (e.g. consider what happens if one of those copy-assignments throws an exception) — it will also make your code more *efficient*, because the vector will track its own capacity separately from its length, and use geometric resizing to make sure that a sequence of `O(n)` calls to `PushHeap` results in only `O(lg n)` reallocations, instead of `O(n)` reallocations. It will also make your source code *shorter*, because you can get rid of those `Allocate()` and `Resize()` functions.

You can also get rid of all your special member functions (as the Rule of Zero suggests), which will shorten the code even more.

---

Finally, you might not be aware that even [`make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap), [`push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) and [`pop_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) are available as standard library functions!

The one heap-related function that I wish were available in the STL that currently isn't available is basically your `ReplaceRoot`, which pops the top element and then *also* pushes the provided element onto the heap in a single operation (which, as you noticed, can be done more efficiently than just a pop plus a push).

---

I have a ["heap_span" on my GitHub](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/ring_view/blob/master/heap_span.h) that's similar to this code but doesn't even use a `vector` for storage; it just provides a view onto a sequence of elements allocated by the caller. It might or might not interest you. :)

Comment: I will never implement a template again without those test cases @Quuxplusone :)  Am I wrong that grouping variables from largest to smallest at the top of a function helps the compiler align them in memory in a more cache-friendly way? Does that only apply in class/struct declarations? If so, is the popular consensus that distributing them make it equally readable? I read through your `heap_span`, its a great example for a lot of the `noexcept`, perfect forwarding, and memory footprint reduction I ought to integrate in my future code. I enjoyed how you did in 200 lines what took me 700.

Comment: "Am I wrong that grouping variables from largest to smallest at the top of a function helps the compiler align them in memory in a more cache-friendly way?" — Yup. It matters for class/struct members because those actually correspond to storage layout; but inside a function, the local variables will be stored in registers or even further optimized away. If I say `int f() { int x = 42; int y = x + 7; return y; }`, then most likely the compiler won't allocate any space for either `x` or `y`, because it can figure out that I mean simply `int f() { return 49; }`.